# Assigning a user flow to an application

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How does one assign a specific user flow to an application in AzureAD B2C? I am able to create one but I can't figure out how to assign it to a specific registered application

Comment: Please explain with your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

User Flows in Azure AD B2C can be executed against any Application Registration that is registered as a B2C application registration. You can see all the App Registrations that are available to execute your User Flow against the list of Apps in the 'Run Now' menu.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't answer my query. The system allows me to create numerous user flows. My question is how do I target one of the user flows to a specific application amongst the ones registered?

Comment: You pass in a PolicyId parameter in the auth request, allowing an app to target the policy you want. There is no “assignment”.

Comment: in which screen does one specify this policy Id in azure portal for an app since there is no assignment process?

Comment: The “Run Now” links are generated per policy, and you choose the App registration to target, those two parameters are enough to build an auth request (when using the portal). In a real app, you target a specific app registration by passing a client id and a specific policy by passing a policyid. The combinations has no restriction. It’s a many to many relationship.